# Reading Instruments and using it to fix zombie

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am getting a `BAD_ACCESS` error whenever I click a button to go to my next scene.

I used Instruments/Zombies to get this reading

[image]

From what it says, MainMenuNew, which is my first scene I use to direct users to a different scene is somehow the zombie?

The methods in "Responsible Caller" are none of my methods, they are either cocos2d methods or system methods.

I have also tried enabling ARC To see if that would help but the same error shows up unfortunately. I've also tried running my app with NSZombies enabled and the option checked in diagnostics for Zombie Objects and come up with this error.

[image]

As you can see in the console there's also this message

```
2014-03-26 16:49:43.449 CountingApp[760:60b] *** -[MainMenuNew respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x166a9800
```

Any ideas at all on how to get rid of this zombie? I will try to post relevant code below, let me know if you need any more.

My scene method (standard method for cocos2d v2.0 template)

```
 +(CCScene *) scene
{
    // scene is an autorelease object.
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    // layer is an autorelease object.
    MainMenuNew *layer = [MainMenuNew node];

    // add layer as a child to scene


    //[scene addChild:rectLayer];
    [scene addChild: layer];

    // return the scene
    return scene;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

I had my picker views delegates set to my MainMenu, so when I changed scenes it caused the zombies.

What I don't understand is why this wasn't an issue since iOS 7.1 (been like this since iOS5)

I just had to do `pickerView.delegate = nil;` before switching scenes.